# How to slice the x-axis according to date

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here is the x and y axis I wanted to plot in `matplotlib`, I can see the graph, but I want it to be evenly sliced according to `Date`, how can I do that? (Right now it leaves space when the date shift from `0131` to `0201` etc

```
           Date  Sessions
0    20170101       150
1    20170102       257
2    20170103       544
3    20170104       490
4    20170105       523
5    20170106       412
6    20170107       164
7    20170108       203
..          ...       ...
213  20170802       483
214  20170803       379
215  20170804       424
216  20170805       128
```

Comment: You should probably convert your dates your proper datetimes, then google "matplotlib plot dates".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create datetime objects:

```
date=datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring,"%Y%m%d")
```

matplotlib can use datetime objects as indicator for the x axes.
If you want nice formating, look at [this example.](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html)

Comment: Looks good, I have several formatting issue there, I looked at the exact tutorial, but thought I could use string to format the x-axis (apparently I have to convert it to `datetime` before using it